# Rails Webpacker: Stop logging "Nothing to do"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Is there a way to stop Webpacker logging that there is nothing to do. I'm getting repeated entries of:

```
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
```

Which is just a waste of a log line.

Answer (score 4):

It's defined here:
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/d836e34dc85b97f8c29a02286d8c93ecef980e58/lib/webpacker/compiler.rb#L30

So maybe override this method, for example something simple like this:
`app/config/initializers/webpacker.rb`

```rb
Webpacker::Compiler.class_eval do
  def compile
    if stale?
      run_webpack.tap do |success|
        record_compilation_digest
      end
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why on earth is that logging at :info level grrrhhhh

Comment: That's useful, but I'm not too happy with monkey patching as a solution. I've raised a Webapaker issue: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2392